# Prove the space of bounded sequences is Banach

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/121.1.00s/exam1sol.pdf

Here is a proof, but I cannot fully understand why it does not give a proof that $x$ is a bounded sequence (i.e. $x$ is in the space). It seems that the proof only shows that the Cauchy sequence in the space converges to $x$. But $x$ is not shown to be definitely in the space.

Comment: $\|x_n - x\| \to 0$ implies that $x$ is in the space. Try to check it.

Comment: Why is this true? This only implies the limit of xn is x but x may not be in the space.

Comment: Use $\|x\| \le \|x_n -x\|+ \|x_n\|$.

Comment: Oh, I see. It is crystal clear now! Many thanks!